# Finish current album and queue next album

Tags: itunes, windows

In iTunes 12 how do I finish the current album and then queue another album. I then want both albums to repeat (back to the start of the first album after the second one completes).

I have set "Repeat All" via the controls menu (can't see any other way to do that) but can't see how to queue the next album.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a playlist with those two albums, then when you play it, it will loop the whole playlist.

(I tested using the Up Next feature but it will not loop tracks played through Up Next.)